# Intel AVX: 256-bits version of dot product for double precision floating point variables

Tags: c++, performance, simd, avx

The Intel Advanced Vector Extensions (AVX) offers no **dot product in the 256-bit version (YMM register) for double precision floating point variables**. The "Why?" question have been very briefly treated in another forum ([here](http://www.amdzone.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=532&t=139130)) and on Stack Overflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033266/intel-avx-why-is-there-no-256-bits-version-of-dot-product-for-double-precision)). But the question I am facing is how to replace this missing instruction with other AVX instructions in an efficient way?

The dot product in 256-bit version exists for single precision floating point variables ([reference here](http://denali.princeton.edu/IntelXe2011/compiler_c/main_cls/intref_cls/common/intref_avx_dp_ps.htm)):

```
 __m256 _mm256_dp_ps(__m256 m1, __m256 m2, const int mask);
```

The idea is to find an efficient equivalent for this missing instruction:

```
 __m256d _mm256_dp_pd(__m256d m1, __m256d m2, const int mask);
```

To be more specific, the code I would like to transform from `__m128` (four floats) to `__m256d` (4 doubles) use the following instructions:

```
   __m128 val0 = ...; // Four float values
   __m128 val1 = ...; //
   __m128 val2 = ...; //
   __m128 val3 = ...; //
   __m128 val4 = ...; //

   __m128 res = _mm_or_ps( _mm_dp_ps(val1,  val0,   0xF1),
                _mm_or_ps( _mm_dp_ps(val2,  val0,   0xF2),
                _mm_or_ps( _mm_dp_ps(val3,  val0,   0xF4),
                           _mm_dp_ps(val4,  val0,   0xF8) )));
```

The result of this code is a `_m128` vector of four floats containing the results of the dot products between `val1` and `val0`, `val2` and `val0`, `val3` and `val0`, `val4` and `val0`.

Maybe this can give hints for the suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I should keep double precision in my application.

Comment: Besides, the conversion+float dot product would take more time than the double dot product.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would use a 4*double multiplication, then a `hadd` (which unfortunately adds only 2*2 floats in the upper and lower half), extract the upper half (a shuffle should work equally, maybe faster) and add it to the lower half.

The result is in the low 64 bit of `dotproduct`.

```
__m256d xy = _mm256_mul_pd( x, y );
__m256d temp = _mm256_hadd_pd( xy, xy );
__m128d hi128 = _mm256_extractf128_pd( temp, 1 );
__m128d dotproduct = _mm_add_pd( (__m128d)temp, hi128 );
```

Edit:
After an idea of Norbert P. I extended this version to do 4 dot products at one time.

```
__m256d xy0 = _mm256_mul_pd( x[0], y[0] );
__m256d xy1 = _mm256_mul_pd( x[1], y[1] );
__m256d xy2 = _mm256_mul_pd( x[2], y[2] );
__m256d xy3 = _mm256_mul_pd( x[3], y[3] );

// low to high: xy00+xy01 xy10+xy11 xy02+xy03 xy12+xy13
__m256d temp01 = _mm256_hadd_pd( xy0, xy1 );   

// low to high: xy20+xy21 xy30+xy31 xy22+xy23 xy32+xy33
__m256d temp23 = _mm256_hadd_pd( xy2, xy3 );

// low to high: xy02+xy03 xy12+xy13 xy20+xy21 xy30+xy31
__m256d swapped = _mm256_permute2f128_pd( temp01, temp23, 0x21 );

// low to high: xy00+xy01 xy10+xy11 xy22+xy23 xy32+xy33
__m256d blended = _mm256_blend_pd(temp01, temp23, 0b1100);

__m256d dotproduct = _mm256_add_pd( swapped, blended );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this works well. I have edited my question in order to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the last line ? I am not shure to understand it well. Isn't it `_mm256_add_pd` ?

Comment: @gleeen.gould: Yes, you are right. Better look twice, this code is untested :-) If you are using gcc, you can use `__v4df` instead of `__m256d` and `*` or `+` instead of the mul/add intrinsics. This works well, it does select the correct vector operations and avoids the hassle

Comment: I still have difficulties to understand it. I would use the following instead of the two last lines :  

`__m256d swapped1   = _mm256_permute2f128_pd( temp01, temp23, 0x30 );
__m256d swapped2   = _mm256_permute2f128_pd( temp01, temp23, 0x21 );
__m256d dotproduct = _mm256_add_pd( swapped1, swapped2 );`

Code untested (I do not have AVX on my machine :-) )

Comment: @gleeen.gould This should work too. My solution uses the fact that addition is commutative. I will add some more comments later

Comment: @drhirsch: great idea. But gleeen.gould is right, you need an extra shuffle. I recommend: `__m256d swapped = _mm256_permute2f128_pd( temp01, temp23, 0x21 ); __m256d mixed = _mm256_blend_pd(temp01, temp23, 12); __m256d dotproduct = _mm256_add_pd( swapped, mixed );`. The sole reason being that `VPERM2F128` takes 2 cycles vs. 1 cycle of `VBLENDPD`. (Hope I got the constants right)

Comment: @NorbertP. Thanks, I didn't know `VBLENDPD`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I updated it to the lates version. BLENDPD is a good idea

Comment: @drhirsch: check the variable names in the last two lines, and the type of `dotproduct` should be `__m256d`. ;)

Comment: @NorbertP. : just checked the constants for `VPERM2F128` and `VBLENDPD` (using Intrinsics Guide for Intel AVX2 v2.6.2, [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/avx/) ). Latencies are 1 for both of them, throughput is 1 for `VPERM2F128` and 0.5 for `VBLENDPD`.

Comment: @gleeen.gould: Is AVX2 already out? I thought it was [coming to Haswell in 2013](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions#CPUs_with_AVX2). I was talking about the current generation of AVX on Sandy Bridge: see [Agner Fog's instruction tables](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf), p. 129.

Comment: Note: Even with `AVX2` and `vpermpd` the solution using `vextractf128` and `addpd` has a lower combined latency than a consequent application of `vpermpd` and `vhaddpd` to generate the horizontal sum.

Comment: Your one-vector dot product is inefficient (don't use `hadd` with the same input twice.)  I think your 4-dot-product solution looks great, though.

Answer (score 12):

I would extend [drhirsch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10454420/733582) to perform two dot products at the same time, saving some work:

```
__m256d xy = _mm256_mul_pd( x, y );
__m256d zw = _mm256_mul_pd( z, w );
__m256d temp = _mm256_hadd_pd( xy, zw );
__m128d hi128 = _mm256_extractf128_pd( temp, 1 );
__m128d dotproduct = _mm_add_pd( (__m128d)temp, hi128 );
```

Then `dot(x,y)` is in the low double and `dot(z,w)` is in the high double of `dotproduct`.

Comment: I'm trying it with Visual Studio 2022 and I'm obtaining an error: `error C2440: 'type cast': cannot convert from '__m256d' to '__m128d'`. Best way to fix it?

Answer (score 7):

For a single dot-product, it's simply a vertical multiply and horizontal sum (see [Fastest way to do horizontal float vector sum on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86)).  `hadd` costs 2 shuffles + an `add`.  It's almost always sub-optimal for throughput when used with both inputs = the same vector.

```
// both elements = dot(x,y)
__m128d dot1(__m256d x, __m256d y) {
    __m256d xy = _mm256_mul_pd(x, y);

    __m128d xylow  = _mm256_castps256_pd128(xy);   // (__m128d)cast isn't portable
    __m128d xyhigh = _mm256_extractf128_pd(xy, 1);
    __m128d sum1 =   _mm_add_pd(xylow, xyhigh);

    __m128d swapped = _mm_shuffle_pd(sum1, sum1, 0b01);   // or unpackhi
    __m128d dotproduct = _mm_add_pd(sum1, swapped);
    return dotproduct;
}
```

If you only need one dot product, this is better than @hirschhornsalz's single-vector answer by 1 shuffle uop on Intel, and a bigger win on AMD Jaguar / Bulldozer-family / Ryzen because it narrows down to 128b right away instead of doing a bunch of 256b stuff.   AMD splits 256b ops into two 128b uops.

---

It can be worth using `hadd` in cases like doing 2 or 4 dot products in parallel where you're using it with 2 different input vectors.  Norbert's `dot` of two pairs of vectors looks optimal if you want the results packed.  I don't see any way to do better even with AVX2 `vpermpd` as a lane-crossing shuffle.

**Of course if you really want one larger `dot` (of 8 or more `double`s), use vertical `add` (with multiple accumulators to hide `vaddps` latency) and do the horizontal summing at the end.**  You can also use `fma` if available.

---

`haddpd` internally shuffles `xy` and `zw` together two different ways and feeds that to a vertical `addpd`, and that's what we'd do by hand anyway.  If we kept `xy` and `zw` separate, we'd need 2 shuffles + 2 adds for each one to get a dot product (in separate registers).  So by shuffling them together with `hadd` as a first step, we save on the total number of shuffles, only on adds and total uop count.

```
/*  Norbert's version, for an Intel CPU:
    __m256d temp = _mm256_hadd_pd( xy, zw );   // 2 shuffle + 1 add
    __m128d hi128 = _mm256_extractf128_pd( temp, 1 ); // 1 shuffle (lane crossing, higher latency)
    __m128d dotproduct = _mm_add_pd( (__m128d)temp, hi128 ); // 1 add
     // 3 shuffle + 2 add
*/
```

But for AMD, where `vextractf128` is very cheap, and 256b `hadd` costs 2x as much as 128b `hadd`, it could make sense to narrow each 256b product down to 128b separately and then combine with a 128b hadd.

Actually, according to [Agner Fog's tables](http://agner.org/optimize/), `haddpd xmm,xmm` is 4 uops on Ryzen.  (And the 256b ymm version is 8 uops).  So it's actually better to use 2x `vshufpd` + `vaddpd` manually on Ryzen, if that data is right.  It might not be: his data for Piledriver has 3 uop `haddpd xmm,xmm`, and it's only 4 uops with a memory operand.  It doesn't make sense to me that they couldn't implement `hadd` as only 3 (or 6 for ymm) uops.

---

For doing 4 `dot`s with the results packed into one `__m256d`,  the exact problem asked, I think @hirschhornsalz's answer looks very good for Intel CPUs.  I haven't studied it super-carefully, but combining in pairs with `hadd` is good.  `vperm2f128` is efficient on Intel (but quite bad on AMD: 8 uops on Ryzen with one per 3c throughput).